# como obtener de un post su header authorization bearer angular

Tags: angular, typescript, jwt

Estoy creando un login  en angular **typescript**  y consumiendo apirest con **spring scurity** y **jwt** en **spring boot** .

Me Encontre con un error muy inusual cuando me trato de logear me trae en el Headers Authorization null o unefined apesar que el usuario y la contraseña son los mismo de la base de datos brindo todo la informacion correspondiente al caso :

cree mi modelo de tipo interface que obtendra como parametro lo siguiente :

```
export interface login{
    username  : string;
    password : string
  }
```

declare mi servicio del api para que me genere el token

```
  crearToken(crear: login) {
    return this.http.post('http://localhost:8077/rest/tokenCreated', {
      username: crear.username,
      password: crear.password
    }, { observe: 'response' })
      .pipe(
        map((response: HttpResponse<any>) => {
          console.log('body: ', response);

          if (response.status === 200 && response.headers.has('Authorization')) {
            const bearerToken = response.headers.get('Authorization')!;
            const token = bearerToken.replace('Bearer ', '');
            console.log(token);

            localStorage.setItem('token', token);
          } else {
            console.error('No se pudo obtener el token');
          }
        }),
        catchError((error) => {
          console.error('Error al obtener el token: ', error);
          return of(error);
        })
      );
  }
```

cree la funcion **validar()** esto es donde el usuario de logearia:

```
  token: login = {
    username: '11111111111Kirby',
    password: '123456'
  }

  Validar() {
    console.log(this.token);
    
    this.serviceAduser.crearToken(this.token).subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data); //linea 205
      
    });
   }
```

pero cuando se logeara vota el siguiente error esto es lo que se muestra en la consola:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero en mi network  me vota lo siguiente

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por ultimo tambien muestro la peticion que le hago al postman de tipo post y me trae status 200 la cual significa que esta funcionando correctamente

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

espero que me ayuden a resolver el error , gracias :D

Answer (score 1):

No todos los "headers" son accesibles desde el cliente. Para permitir el acceso a ciertos "headers" el servidor debe enviar el "header" `Access-Control-Expose-Headers`.

Ejemplo:

`Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Authorization`

[Referencia](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Expose-Headers)

Comment: Lo resolvi de la siguiente manera  cree un clase y lo intancie con el **OncePerRequestFilter** => `response.setHeader("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "*");`